# Install and load Tidymodels package in AML

Tags: r, azure, r-package, azure-machine-learning-service, tidymodels

I'm trying install and load some R packages in the Execute R Script in Azure Machine Learning for to run models, such as **tidymodels, timetk, modeltime, modeltime.ensemble**.

```
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
install.packages("quantdates",repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
install.packages("tidymodels",repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
library(quantdates)
library(tidymodels) 
library(timetk) 
library(modeltime) 
library(modeltime.resample) 
library(modeltime.ensemble)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required

azureml_main(input_dataframe_1), library(tidymodels), tryCatch({
    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)
}, error = function(e) {
    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
        paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1])
    else ""
    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
    if (logical.return) 
        message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
}), tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers), tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1]]), value[[3]](cond), stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA), .handleSimpleError(function (e) 
{
    error_msg <<- paste(toString(e), toString(sys.calls()[-c(1:3)]), sep = "\n")
    stop(e)
}, "package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):\n namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required", quote(NULL)), h(simpleError(msg, call))
'.
---------- End of error message from R  interpreter  ----------
```

I have also tried with devtools package for install a particular version but I keep getting the same error with the **rlang package**. Sometimes, I get the same error with the **cli package**.

In my local machine, the R code runs fine. I have the R version 4.1.3 and the Azure Machine Learning has the R version 3.5.1.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: the error message says an older version of rlang is already loaded & at least 1.0.2 is required - maybe try restarting R then running `update.packages()` before loading any libraries

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that version issue was raised.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required
```

**Cause:** When we try to attach the notebook to the cluster, R namespace will not be refreshed. When there is a dependency of new package versions, the newer packages will be downloaded through **CRAN** but not loaded.

**Solution:** The best way to achieve this is to install packages as **[Cluster-Installed libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/#install-a-library-on-a-cluster)**

Check the [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/notebooks-r-libraries) for better implementation of package installation.